# SRID not updating

Tags: postgis, point, srid

I have created a point geometry using `ST_GeomFromText` function in PostGIS and simultaneous set the SRID to 3857.

```
Alter table data.trips_42779
add column geom geometry;

UPDATE data.trips_42779
SET geom_start = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || start_lon || ' ' || start_lat || ')', 3857);
```

However, when I check the SRID using the below query it shows SRID as 0 (see first row in the table in the image below).

```
select * from geometry_columns;
```

[image]

Also spatial join with any layer that has SRID as 3857 returns NULL.
How can I set the SRID of point layer created from Lon/Lat correctly to EPSG:3857 ?

Comment: You have an extra problem here:  You can't use longitude and latitude as values into a point in Web Mercator without mapping within ~200 meters of the origin of [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island).  You need to reproject the WGS84 GCS coords to 3857, as in `ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(start_lon,start_lat),4326),3857)`

Comment: Thanks . This was helpful. Perhaps you can add this comment to the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you're just querying the metadata of the tables, so because you didn't specify a CRS when creating the table, you'll get 0 for the SRID.

If you create the table this way:

```
Alter table data.trips_42779
add column geom geometry(Point, 3857);
```

Then you'll get an SRID value.

However, what does the following return?

```
select ST_SRID(geom_start) from trips_42799
```